# What is the use of a service when using the Location API Android?

Tags: java, android, service, location, google-play-services

I managed to get a location object as per the documentation available in the [Android Developers website](https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions) (using the Location API offered by Google Play Services). Although I have specified service as the documentation instructs, I am never binding it/ starting it/ using it anywhere. I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you are not doing anything wrong. It is a requirement for devices with Android 10 (API level 29).

As [Google Docs](https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions) Says

> When a foreground service is running, the system raises user awareness
> by showing a persistent notification. Your app retains access when
> it's placed in the background, such as when the user presses the Home
> button on their device or turns their device's display off.

So basically if you are using location it will just show the notification to user if they have android 10 i.e API level 29